# Change some numerical values in data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a dataframe with incorrect values for two variables (Lat and Lon).  The incorrect values in the dataframe are listed as 999.00, and the correct values should be 42.68 and -72.47, respectively.

I would like an easy way to replace these values using dplyr, but my attempts (see below) have been unsuccessful (errors provided below).

```
df$Lat2 <- recode(df$Lat, "999.00"="42.68", .default=x)
```

> Error in lapply(x, f) : object 'x' not found

```
df <- df %>%
mutate(Lat2 = if_else(Lat == 999.00, 42.68, NULL, NULL))
```

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
>     Evaluation error: unused argument (recvLat = 999).

```
df <- df %>%
mutate(Lat2 = ifelse(Lat == 999.00, 42.68, NULL))
```

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
>     Evaluation error: replacement has length zero.
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In rep(no, length.out = length(ans)) :
>     'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL

```
df <- df %>%
mutate(Lat2 = case_when(Lat == 999.00 ~ 42.68, TRUE ~ NULL))
```

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
>     Evaluation error: subscript out of bounds.

For the latter three attempts, I get the same error if the number are in quotes (i.e. "999.00" and "42.68")

Comment: Your `ifelse` statement should have the actual column as the alternative, not `NULL`, i.e. `ifelse(..,..., df$Lat)`

Comment: couldn't this be solved using `df$Lat <- df$Lat %>% gsub("999.00", "42.68")`?

Comment: @huan... No. `df$Lat` is a numeric variable, not a string

Comment: Something like: 
as_tibble(df) %>% mutate(Lon  = case_when(revcLat == 999 ~ 42.68), Lat2 = case_when(Lat == 999 ~ -72.47))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can place `NULL` in a `list`

```
df %>%
    mutate(Lat2 = ifelse(recvLat == 999.00, 42.68, list(NULL)))
#  recvLat  Lat2
#1   999.0 42.68
#2     1.5  NULL
#3     2.5  NULL
```

Instead of `NULL`, it can be `NA`

```
df %>%
    mutate(Lat2 = ifelse(recvLat == 999.00, 42.68, NA_real_))
#  recvLat  Lat2
#1   999.0 42.68
#2     1.5    NA
#3     2.5    NA
```

If we want to do the opposite, just use `!=`

```
df %>%
    mutate(Lat2 = ifelse(recvLat != 999.00, 42.68, NA_real_))
```

Based on the OP's comment,

```
df %>%
    mutate(Lat2 = ifelse(recvLat == 999.00, 42.68, recvLat))
```

---

In `base R`, we can do this by creating an index

```
i1 <- df$recvLat == 999
df$recLat[i1] <- 42.68
```

NOTE: Both the solutions work.

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(recvLat = c(999, 1.5,  2.5))
```

Comment: I odn't get the error message anymore, but I want to keep all the original vales that were not 999, not turn those into NULLs

Comment: @user3220999  Please check your code `mutate(Lat2 = ifelse(recvLat == 999.00, 42.68, NULL))`  It is the same code I used here.  Here, the condition is that values that are 999, changed to 42.68 and others to `NULL`

Comment: @user3220999  I don't understand the problem now.  You have showed the code to assign values to `NULL` and now it is not needed??

Comment: ah, I made an error, the first ifelse statement should have been if_else.  I want all the 999's to be 42.68, and to keep all other values, not turn them into NULLs

Answer (score 2):

why not use this.

```
data=as.data.frame(matrix(0,3,3))
names(data)=c("a","b","c")
data$a[1]=999
data$c[2]=999
data$a[which(data$a==999)]=42.68
data$c[which(data$c==999)]=-72.47
data
      a b      c
1 42.68 0   0.00
2  0.00 0 -72.47
3  0.00 0   0.00
```

Comment: First four lines just recreate the data. You only need the last two to correct your data.

Comment: is there no way to do this in dplyr?  I need to keep my variables within my dataframe for futher analyses.

Comment: I don't quite understand. This way, all variables are kept in your dataframe, the only difference is the updated values in the Lat and Lon columns. You can even save the index of those points that were corrected

Comment: ah.  I misunderstood what you were doing on my initial read through.  while I prefer to work in dplyr, I can see this is also pretty simple and effective.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is a nice case to show the elegance of `data.table` as well.

```
library(data.table)

## Create example
data <- data.table(lat = c(999, 0, 0),
                   lon = c(0, 999, 0))

## Reassign values
data[lat==999, lat := 42.68]
data[lon==999, lon := -72.47]

## Print results
data
#      lat    lon
# 1: 42.68   0.00
# 2:  0.00 -72.47
# 3:  0.00   0.00
```

The downside is that you have to remember that `:=` is needed for assignment.

The upsides are

- You can refer to variables by name without quotes
- Memory efficient, especially important for large data sets
- Doesn't have dependencies
- The `data.table` syntax is much simpler and consistent (i, j, group by)
- You don't need to memorize a bunch of functions with weird names that may and/or may not be spelled Aussie style (like colour or summarise)
- You can use base R more, which makes your code more portable and widely understood
- The data.table class inherits the data.frame class, so it's more compatible within R

Comment: Thanks @geneorama, but I was hoping to stick to dplyr functions.

Comment: @user3220999 no problem!  The dplyr is definitely a great place to start, especially for more experimental R usage.